# Fastest way to find if a lot numbers are in multiple intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

So I have a task. I've been given \$n\$ numbers and \$m\$ intervals and I need to figure out how many numbers are in the \$m\$ \$i\$-th interval. I've written some code with a complexity of \$O(n \times m)\$, though I need to optimize it more. Any help? Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin.tie(0);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    int n,m,temp,temp1;
    vector <pair<int, int>> uogienes;
    vector <int> erskeciai;

cin >> n >> m;
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++){
    cin>>temp;
    erskeciai.push_back(temp);
}
temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){
    cin>> temp >> temp1;
    uogienes.push_back(make_pair(temp, temp1));
}
for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){
        temp=0;
    for(int h = 0; h<n; h++){
       if(uogienes[i].first <= erskeciai[h] && uogienes[i].second >= erskeciai[h]){
        temp++;
        }
    }
cout  << temp << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the spacing. The easiest way is to paste in the correctly-spaced code, select the whole thing, and then click on the "Code" icon in the toolbar or press control-K.

Answer (score 3):

## Review

Please don't use `using namespace;` on the gobal scope. It's [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Next, try to keep the scope of your variables smaller. Also indent your code properly to make it easier for you (and others) to see the program flow.

Don't include `bits/c++`. It's not a standard header. It's somewhat OK in programming challenges, but you should use the proper includes in your real/production code.

If you use a smaller scope for your variables, you will also be able to use better names for them, for example `lower` instead of `temp` and `upper` instead of `temp1`.

If we apply these changes (and translate your names into English), we end up with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cin.tie(0);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    std::cout.tie(0);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ranges;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    int number_count, range_count;

    std::cin >> number_count >> range_count;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_count; i++){
        int number;
        std::cin >> number;
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < range_count; i++){
        int lower, upper;
        std::cin >> lower >> upper;
        ranges.push_back({lower, upper});
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < range_count; i++){        
        int count = 0;

        for(int h = 0; h <number_count; h++){
            if(ranges[i].first <= numbers[h] && ranges[i].second >= numbers[h]){
                count++;
            }
        }
        std::cout << count << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would be even better to use the proper types and more functions for I/O.

## Performance

Instead of \$\mathcal O(nm)\$, you can get \$\mathcal O((n+m) \log n)\$ if you `std::sort` the numbers and then use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`.